# OkHttp SSL Certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, okhttp

So i am developing an app which uses a rest connection to a database server. This server uses TLS encryption and has a SSL certificate. Im using OkHttp3.2 to manage my server connection. I can connect to the server without any problems and also encryption works fine.

My question is based on the certificate tester from java's SSL Engine. I can readout everything the Server send about the certificate (Serial, Signature...) but i cant see any information about validation or trust level like a certificate chain.

Does the SSL Engine tests the Certificate independently or do i have to do this manually?

And would OkHttp's certificate pinning do the Job?

And how would i readout the SHA checksum of the certificate like some ssl tester do? e.g. ssllabs.com

Comment: I hope this link will be helpful for you. https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: @PravinDivraniya I've read the documentary of okhttp, but it says only that by default, okhttp trusts a certificate. But i want to check the certificate validity mannually by a thirt party service.

Comment: According to this link certificate pinning might do the job for you. http://artemzin.com/blog/certificate-pinning-notes-for-android-java/

Answer (score 0):

So Thanks to Pravin's comment i think i know everything i need.

If someone is intrested a little conclusion of the article:

Android's SSL Engine checkes validity of the Certificate at every Request. The Certificate is compared with trustet root certificates in **local system storage** (Settings -> Security -> Trusted credentials).

Certificate pinning would add a second security level, in fact it checkes if a certificate in the certificate-chain has a fringerprint which is equal to your setting. Usefull if you would only want to allow a certifiace of a specified provider to communicade with your app.